# Background Task at a specific time

Tags: c#, uwp, background-task

I want to schedule a background task at a particular DateTime.Timeofday . I researched a lot and found out that TimeTrigger is the only way that too in not accurate. 
my code is:

```
private async void RegisterBackgroundTask()
    {
        var taskName = "TileUpdateTask";

        var backgroundAccessStatus = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
        if (backgroundAccessStatus == BackgroundAccessStatus.AllowedMayUseActiveRealTimeConnectivity || backgroundAccessStatus == BackgroundAccessStatus.AllowedWithAlwaysOnRealTimeConnectivity)
        {
            foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
            {
                if (task.Value.Name == taskName)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            BackgroundTaskBuilder taskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
            taskBuilder.Name = taskName;
            taskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = typeof(BackgroundTasks.TileUpdateTask).FullName;
            taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay,false)); //////////////////////////////here!!!!!!!!
            var registeration = taskBuilder.Register();
        }
    }
```

I also found a same question regarding this, 
[Run Background Task at specific time - UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556127/run-background-task-at-specific-time-uwp)
but this is just a way arround it. Is there any direct approach to it?

Comment: Like a windows scheduler ?  if you don't like the one that windows provides and You don't like the 'WorkAround' - You can always write Your own scheduling service :)

Comment: The official API is to use the BackgroundExecutionManager: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt186458.aspx  The issue is that UWP apps are designed to run on platforms that don't have the windows Scheduler.  That API will run even if your app isn't.  A do-it-yourself approach would only run while your app is running.

Comment: @Marty Yes, a windows scheduler would do, I need anything that can run a background task at a fixed user defined time. for instance, the task runs everyday at 2 pm. This timing must be accurate, unlike the current TimeTrigger one which would run in between 0 to 15 mins from the time of creation. If you suggest writing my own scheduling service, it could be of great help if you could give some links or sample code from which I can refer.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch I am working on an IoT application so technically my application would be running 24*365 so I don't think BackgroundExecutionManager would cause an issue. I went through the doccumentation although it states that it contains how to run a task at a specific time, it doesn't really covers it. Is there any code sample or a blog through which I can go?

Comment: This is the best I could find using my company's crippled internet: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299100.aspx

Comment: @BerinLoritsch the link gives a 502 error stating: 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.

Comment: @AdityaSharma, It's Microsoft's site.  It might be a temporary issue, or a network configuration issue somewhere in between your machine and MSDN.  I click on the link and I can see the article.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is targetting Windows IoT, you can develop a "Background Application (IoT)" which is basically a background task which can run forever.

[image: new projet wizard]

This is limited to the IoT device family.
You will find more details on the project [template page](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533884&clcid=0x409).

Depending on what you need, you can use the app-to-background communication to control the "Background Application (IoT)" from your regular application. See this [walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service) for more details.

Comment: No that's not what I am looking for. I guess it's just not possible. I can only provide a timespan between which at any time the task would run